# image does not load in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have created one folder named "example" in that i have put all images and js and css files and html files

it is looking like below
[image]

i am loading images named abcd.png with below code in manifiest.json

```
       "web_accessible_resources": [
            "abcd.png"  
       ],
```

and another code which is in **SelectedTextnotification.js**

```
divGLXBubbleQuery = document.createElement('div');
divGLXBubbleQuery.id = 'GLXBubbleQuery';
divGLXBubbleQuery.innerHTML = "<img id='klematis lilac' border='0' src='abcd.png' width='150' height='113'>";
```

but image does not load 
[image]

can any body help me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL)**, in order to *"convert a relative path within an extension install directory to a fully-qualified URL"*.

Supposing `SelectedTextnotification.js` is a content script, you should change your cose like this:

```
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("abcd.png");
divGLXBubbleQuery.innerHTML = "<img ... src='" + imgURL + "' ...>";
```